# My dll wont receive keystroes no matter what

Tags: dll, keyboard, hook, keyhook

I have tried numerous times with diffrent types of keyboard hooks and still wont work. Here is my code

```
#include <Windows.h>


HWND window1 = FindWindow(NULL, "Window Title 1");
HWND window2 = FindWindow(NULL, "Window Title 2");


void SwitchWindows(HWND currentWindow, HWND nextWindow) {
    ShowWindow(currentWindow, SW_HIDE);  // Hide the current window
    ShowWindow(nextWindow, SW_SHOW);    // Show the next window
}


LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {`your text`
    if (nCode >= 0) {
        if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN) {
            KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* kbdStruct = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
            // Detect the key press you want to use for switching windows (e.g., F1)
            if (kbdStruct->vkCode == VK_F1) {
                // Switch from window1 to window2
                SwitchWindows(window1, window2);
            } else if (kbdStruct->vkCode == VK_F2) {
                // Switch from window2 to window1
                SwitchWindows(window2, window1);
            }
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved) {
    switch (ul_reason_for_call) {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            // Install the keyboard hook
            HHOOK hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardProc, hModule, 0);
            break;
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            // Unhook and clean up
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook);
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

and yes i have enterd my windows names. Can anyone help

i want it to find two specific windows and switch between them based on what key is pressed.